# Disable indoor in Street View panorama view (android)

Tags: android, google-street-view

I am trying to disable indoor view in the StreetViewPanoramaView on Android. But I can't find any method in the documentation. This is my code:

```
StreetViewPanoramaView streetViewPan = (StreetViewPanoramaView) findViewById(R.id.streetView);

streetViewPan.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: Please let me know if you find a workarond/solution. As far as I know you cannot disable indoor panoramas on Android.